# How to get the actual resized size of the Android Virtual Device?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-virtual-device

I am working on a visual testing tool for Android applications. To obtain screen captures compatible with other existing tools (e.g., Sikuli) I would need to know the exact screen size of the Android Virtual Device on which the app is run. Is there any way to get it programmatically?

I have tried to use the methods of the Display class:

```
            Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
            Point size = new Point();
            display.getSize(size);
            int display_width = size.x;
            int display_height = size.y;
```

This however always return the resolution of the emulated device (1920*1080 in my case) and not the actual resized dimensions on the desktop PC screen.

Comment: I think there is no way to get this info, cause OS inside emulator has absolutely no idea this it's emulated and mostly about it's window size.

Comment: @AndreiVinogradov that's actually what I feared

Comment: Why should you know it? There are a lot of testing frameworks that can test UI in Android.

Comment: You can take a look on how, for example, Espresso works. Source code available here: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/testing/+/android-support-test/espresso/core/src/main/java/android/support/test/espresso

Comment: The idea was to take screenshots that could be used by other general-purpose visual testing tools. It is proving harder than I expected tbh. Thanks for the pointer

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you right and the only purpose - is taking screenshots from virtual device - you can do the following:

1) Take the screenshot using the following command (you can change screenshot.png if you want to call it something else): adb shell screencap -p /sdcard/screenshot.png.

2) Pull the picture onto your computer: adb pull /sdcard/screenshot.png.

3) Remove the screenshot from your device: adb shell rm /sdcard/screenshot.png.

Comment: This will take a 1920*1080 screenshot not resized to the exact size of the AVD on my monitor.

Comment: As I think - the only option for you - find AVD window using your OS api and take it's screenshot that way.